# Reading an Image (standard format png,jpeg etc) and writing the Image Data to a binary file using Objective C

Tags: cocoa, image, binary

I am pretty new to Objective C and working with Cocoa Framework. I want to read an image and then extract the image data (just pixel data and not  the header) and then write the data to a binary file. I am kind of stuck with this, I was going through the methods of `NSImage` but I couldn't find a suitable one. Can anyone suggest me some other ways of doing this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? What format is that "binary file" you need? (Image data without headers is not often very useful, unless you have very specific needs/context)

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am dealing only with 8 bit greyscale images. So the idea is to get each pixel information (row-wise) and store each pixel as unsigned char. The binary file will have all the pixel information in that format.

Answer (score 0):

Cocoa-wise, the easiest approach is to use the `NSBitmapImageRep` class. Once initialized with a `NSData` object, for example, you can access the color value at any coordinate as a `NSColor` object using the `-setColor:atX:y:` and `-colorAtX:y:` methods. Note that if you call these methods in tight loops, you may suffer a performance hit from `objc_msg_send`. You could consider accessing the raw bitmap data as C array via the `-bitmapData` method. When dealing with a RGB image, for example, the color values for each channel are stored at offsets of 3.

For example:

```
color values: [R,G,B][R,G,B][R,G,B]
     indices: [0,1,2, 3,4,5, 6,7,8]
```

To loop through each pixel in the image and extract the RGB components:

```
unsigned char *bitmapData = [bitmapRep bitmapData];

if ([bitmapRep samplesPerPixel] == 3) {
    for (i = 0; i < [image size].width * [image size].height; i++) {
        int base = (i * 3);

        // these range from 0-255
        unsigned char red = bitmapData[base + 0];
        unsigned char green = bitmapData[base + 1];
        unsigned char blue = bitmapData[base + 2];
    }
}
```